# KVM Mutliple Apache Guest VMs

Tags: centos, apache-2.4, kvm-virtualization, haproxy

I want to configure a CentOS 7/8 Host to have multiple KVM VMs running Apache that I can route to from the internet (i.e. Assign a DNS A/CNAME Record). What is the typical configuration for this?

So, for example, I want to have the following DNS records:

```
site1.example.com   26  IN  A   76.81.220.196 -> KVM Guest 1 running Apache
site2.example.com   26  IN  A   76.81.220.196 -> KVM Guest 2 running Apache
```

## **Option 1:**

Set up the host to have a public static IP. Set up KVM Bridge networking, and use IP Tables to route ports to KVM Guests. This sounds like I'll run into conflicts if I run all Apache servers on port 80 however. Described [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Networking)

## **Option 2:**

Host runs a reverse proxy in Apache/HAProxy and then just forwards to the correct KVM Guest set up in KVM as described [here](https://blog.entrostat.com/routing-multiple-domains-using-haproxy-http-and-https-ssl/)

In the case of option 2, will I be able to forward non-standard ports as well? I might have to set up a Windows Guest that uses software on non-standard ports and will want to map those to the public host as well.

### EDIT:

The project I'm dealing with is getting all the random dedicated boxes IT guys have set up over the years onto one (or few) Rack Servers.

I know about the 3rd option of Apache Virtualhosts and use them all the time. The reason why we're looking past that at the moment is because of the need to have multiple PHP versions because I won't have to deal with immediately fixing any bugs that might be caused by using a newer PHP version, and don't need with weird/non-standard configs. I also use Docker often, but because of the proximity of the related project deadline I'm not sure I have time to remap all currently existing dedicated services into Docker.

I essentially need to go "Bob had software ABC on this server, create a VM that does exactly the same thing."

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, the best-practice for such a thing is simply to have 1 instance of apache and use vhosts.  No VMs.  Advantage is that you only need 1 static IP, and resources are not wasted needlessly.

If you (for some reason) really want to run multiple separate instances of apache, consider running everything in containers.  (i.e. Docker, or Kubernetes)  You are still are running two separate instances, but you are not trying to support two complete OSes.  Each container can have its own static IP, or you can NAT from the host machine to the containers.  This is sort of the "middle-ground" area, where you get nearly all the same protections as two isolated VMs, but get a lot of resource-savings, and performance increases.

If you're really crazy enough to want to run two complete OSes as guests inside a 3rd "host" OS, then yeah... I guess you could run two OSes in VMs, and then either simply NAT, or run a proxy service or cluster web service to redirect to individual VMs.

As for which option is "best"? ... that's a huge opinion question, and definitely doesn't fit in the guidelines of Stack-Exchange's policies on asking questions.  (Best is a matter of opinion, and would require a great deal of discussion to understand the goals of your project)

Comment: Removed best from the question as I know SE doesn't like that kind of question. Also added context to project/problem. I essentially get 8-ish hours to migrate 6+ servers to one rack server. Docker would be my ideal solution but getting it approved and doing it in 8 hours would be a fun one.

Comment: Are all of the web-servers getting unique IPs? or only one IP for all sites?

Comment: Each box currently has it's own public static IP, but if I can shrink that down and share 1 Public IP that's the goal.

Comment: Setup an apache box on the host machine, and use `proxy pass` to pass traffic to the guest VMs using private IPs in each VM.  Pretty quick & easy.

Answer (score 0):

The latter. Use a front end proxy (also can be run in VMs or containers) and relay to back ends based on name. Keeps the configuration at the application level, running on the well known port numbers.

NAT is probably unnecessary. The proxy makes its own connection to the backend, which could be on a private network.

Or, a web server can do its own name based virtual hosting, without something in front of it. However, your design is a guest per site.

Non-HTTP applications don't have a host name header and will need some other way to route. Other applications have proxies, or you can write one.

Comment: Gotcha. I might just do all the HTTP/S L7 stuff in HAProxy then and then use IPTables to route the public ip the specific VM that uses non-standard TCP ports (It's the Nightmare of IT, Quickbooks).